Html is displayed as a plain text in ASP.NET Core Razor pages
I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC Razor pages app. On the Login.cshtml page, I want to show the following error message when the user tries to login with in invalid credential:
Invalid: <b>User Name</b> and/or <b>Password</b>

The problem is this message is displayed as a text instead of an html with the "User Name" and "Password" in bold.
This is my C# code in Login.cshtml.cs:
var invalidLogin = await LockOut(Input.UserUserName, Input.Password);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(invalidLogin))
{
    invalidLogin = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(invalidLogin);

    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, invalidLogin);

    return Page();
}

As shown above, I even tried to html encode the message. Still it's displayed as a text,
Invalid: &lt;b&gt;User Name&lt;/b&gt; and/or &lt;b&gt;Password&lt;/b&gt;

Based on Google search, I have verified that the page source has this line at the top:
<!DOCTYPE html>


Look into Html.Raw but you must be cautious of XSS attacks.  It doesn't do the HTML by default as a security measure, but if you validate the values first manually and can be sure its safe, use Html.Raw(String) to get where you are trying to go.

In most cases Html.Raw() is ok. Wraps HTML markup in an HtmlString instance so that it is interpreted as HTML markup. In my project Html.Encode() works as well.

The Html.Raw() is a feasible solution, since you are displaying only some indicative information.
Login.cshtml
@model WebApplication26.Pages.LoginModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
}

<h1>Log in</h1>

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.UserName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.UserName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.Password" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
    </div>

    @if (ModelState.ErrorCount > 0)
    {
        <div class="validation-summary-errors text-danger">
            @foreach (var error in ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors))
            {
               @* <p>@error.ErrorMessage</p> *@
               <p>@Html.Raw(error.ErrorMessage)</p>
            }
        </div>
    }
</form>

Login.cshtml.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication26.Pages
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var invalidLogin = await LockOut(Input.UserName, Input.Password);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(invalidLogin))
            {
                // Add the error message without encoding it
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid: <b>User Name</b> and/or <b>Password</b>");
                return Page();
            }
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }

        private Task<string> LockOut(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (userName != "correctUser" || password != "correctPassword")
            {
                return Task.FromResult("Invalid: <b>User Name</b> and/or <b>Password</b>");
            }

            return Task.FromResult<string>(null);
        }
    }
}


